# Using boost::bind on std::string::find fails to compile

Tags: c++, boost, stl, compiler-errors, boost-bind

I have the following code:

```
int MimeDocument::GetAttachmentId( std::string const& content_id )
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    using boost::lambda::_1;
    using boost::bind;

    int id = 0;

    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it =
        std::find_if( attachment_list_.begin(), attachment_list_.end(),
            bind( &std::string::find, content_id, _1 ) != std::string::npos
        );

    if( it != attachment_list_.end() ) {
        id = std::distance( attachment_list_.begin(), it );
    }

    return id;
}
```

Which when compiled on MSVC9 SP1 results in tons of `C2780` compiler errors. Here are just a few from the top of the list:

```
1>c:\code\work\cmake-mds\server\gmmserver\domino\server\interface\dimime.cpp(210) : error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<_bi::dm_result<MT::* ,A1>::type,boost::_mfi::dm<M,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(M T::* ,A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>        c:\code\work\cmake-mds\build-vc9\third_party\boost\1.48.0\include\boost\bind\bind.hpp(1728) : see declaration of 'boost::bind'
1>c:\code\work\cmake-mds\server\gmmserver\domino\server\interface\dimime.cpp(210) : error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::cmf8<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8>,_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 11 arguments - 3 provided
1>        c:\code\work\cmake-mds\build-vc9\third_party\boost\1.48.0\include\boost\bind\bind_mf2_cc.hpp(223) : see declaration of 'boost::bind'
1>c:\code\work\cmake-mds\server\gmmserver\domino\server\interface\dimime.cpp(210) : error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<Rt2,boost::_mfi::mf8<R,T,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8>,_bi::list_av_9<A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9>::type> boost::bind(boost::type<T>,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8),A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 11 arguments - 3 provided
1>        c:\code\work\cmake-mds\build-vc9\third_party\boost\1.48.0\include\boost\bind\bind_mf2_cc.hpp(212) : see declaration of 'boost::bind'
```

Any compiler errors relating to boost are virtually unreadable and unhelpful to me, so I hope someone can help me figure out what is going on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Taking the address of standard library (member) functions is illegal; I'm not sure why you ignored this comment on your last (deleted) question.

Comment: @ildjarn 2 reasons: 1) I posted too early; my code was crap and 2) You did not explain why (no quotes from the standard, etc). Also your comment does not address the reason for the compiler failure, which even if it is illegal I'd still like to know the reason.

Comment: There are 4 different `std::string::find`. Which one should the compiler select?

Comment: @Robert : Regarding 2), I wasn't trying to answer your question (hence posting a comment rather than an answer), I was merely pointing out that what you're trying to achieve is a lost cause anyway.

Comment: @ildjarn I stated "...Also your ***comment*** does not address...". And you have yet to display any kind of facts behind your reasoning, regardless of the means in which you choose to address my question.

Comment: @Robert : The level of entitlement you're demonstrating is unfortunate -- comments don't _need_ to address anything, otherwise they wouldn't be separate from answers. In any case, my "reasoning" is not relevant, since this "fact" comes straight from the standard: C++03 §17.4.4.4 and associated comment 172.

Comment: @ildjarn I don't have access to the C++03 standard, but 98 and 11 simply say that taking the address of a standard member function will have an unspecified type, not that it's forbidden.

Comment: @Mark : The type will need to be specified in order to disambiguate the overloads, which will then be ill-defined as the type _cannot_ be specified.

Comment: @ildjarn So you disagree that this would compile fine for a non-overloaded function? As far as I can tell, the compiler picks specific types for the functions and since it knows the types it could get the address of that type. `bind` itself doesn't care about the type passed in, only that the parameters it's given can be bound to that function.

Comment: @Mark : The standard also permits an implementation to add arbitrary overloads, and to use overloads instead of default arguments. In the end, unless you're targeting a specific compiler/platform, it is never possible to _portably_ take the address of a standard library member function.

Comment: @ildjarn However certain signatures *must* exist, otherwise what would be the point of the S in STL? I think you're being overly critical here and in *practice* this is a non-issue.

Comment: @ildjarn For you reference: 21.3.6.1. That signature is in the standard, so there is no reason why I can't make a member function pointer for that.

Comment: @Robert : Your fundamental assumption is wrong -- implementations are allowed to add arbitrary default arguments to any function in the standard library. Thus you can never portably know the signature of any (member) function in the standard library. And yes, in practice this _is_ an issue -- you're running into it right now!

Comment: @ildjarn The standard also mentions defining *additional* member functions (apart from those that have been standardized). So it's completely legal to have a member function pointer to one of the *standardized* overloads, but not any of the extended, non-standard overloads, that will have additional parameters with default values. That is my interpretation, at least.

Comment: @ildjarn *An implementation can declare additional non-virtual member function signatures within a class:* -- (read: *additional*)

Comment: @ildjarn And no, this is not my issue. The issue (as I have figured out) is the default parameter. My function pointer does not retain the knowledge of an optional parameter, so boost::bind still expects an explicit value there. It's not an overload resolution issue with std::string::find, it's a missing parameter, which I did not specify because it was default, but boost::bind cannot recognize such.

Comment: @Robert : "*An implementation can declare additional non-virtual member function signatures within a class: **by adding arguments with default values to a member function signature***" An additional signature does not imply an additional member function in this case. So, yes, this _is_ your issue if you're at all concerned about portability, because an implementation is allowed to add as many default arguments as it wants, at which point your `bind` invocation will again break.

Comment: @ildjarn Your argument is incorrect because all of the bullet points apply to the former statement, which is in regards to *additional* overloaded member functions. The member function signature that your bullet point is referring to is that of the *additional* overload, not of an existing one. You are taking this bullet-point out of context for your own benefit.

Comment: @Robert : No, it is additional non-virtual member function _signatures_. Think about that for a minute, please.

Comment: @ildjarn A signature is information about function as it pertains to overload resolution. A function may only have 1 signature, so to add additional signatures implies an additional overload due to this rule. So my argument is valid because of this transitive rule.

Comment: @Robert : No, a function with default arguments has multiple callable signatures. E.g. `void foo(int, int = 0);` has two callable signatures: one supplying a single `int`, and another supplying two.

Comment: @ildjarn A signature is information about a function at the *declaration*, not the call site. Default parameters have nothing to do with the function's signature: i.e., the standard defines that you *redeclare* a function if you do `int foo( int j, int p )` and then `int foo( int j, int p = 0 )`. See 13.1 and 8.3.5

Comment: @ildjarn Also in your example, the same signature is used in both cases, the compiler just conveniently adds in the 2nd parameter for you. Default arguments do not affect overload resolution (same as return values) and thus they are not part of the signature in that sense. See 1.3.10

Comment: I don't have the motivation to continue throwing standard citations at you. The bottom line is very simple: the standard says "*the address of a member function of a class in the C++ standard library has an unspecified type*", but the code you are choosing to use attempts to specify that type. If the type you specify is not the real type, welcome to UB-land.

Comment: @ildjarn The *additional* member functions have an unspecified type, because the vendor has the freedom to add as many parameters with default values as they see fit and the standard cannot foresee those. However, the actual standardized methods remain unchanged and thus their types are known. What's the point of having a STL if it's not *really* standard? Be realistic. Also note `173)` states: *An implementation may also define additional member functions that would otherwise not be called by a valid C++ program.* There's that word "additional" again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are four overloads of `std::string::find`:

```
size_t find(const string& str, size_t pos = 0) const;
size_t find(const char* s, size_t pos, size_t n) const;
size_t find(const char* s, size_t pos = 0) const;
size_t find(char c, size_t pos = 0) const;
```

Therefore one must help the compiler to pick one (resolve ambiguity) by specifying which particular overloaded function the address is taken of, e.g.:

```
boost::bind( static_cast<size_t(std::string::*)(const std::string&, size_t) const>(&std::string::find), content_id, _1, 0)
```

Rather ugly, isn't it?

Note, that `std::string::find()` returns `std::string::npos` (which most often is `size_t(-1)`) on an unsuccessful search. Then it would convert `size_t(-1)` to `bool(true)` and result in `std::find_if()` returning its first argument no matter what the rest of arguments are.

The result of `std::string::find()` needs to be compared against `std::string::npos`. Using `boost::bind` that would look like:

```
// ...

std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = std::find_if(
      attachment_list_.begin()
    , attachment_list_.end()
    , boost::bind(
          std::not_equal_to<std::string::size_type>()
        , std::string::npos
        , boost::bind(
              static_cast<size_t(std::string::*)(const std::string&, size_t) const>(&std::string::find)
            , &content_id // pass by pointer, don't copy
            , _1
            , 0)
            )
    );
```

Which doesn't look too readable either.

It may be a tiny little bit more readable with `boost::lambda::bind`:

```
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

// ...

std::vector<std::string>::iterator it =
    std::find_if(
          attachment_list_.begin()
        , attachment_list_.end()
        , boost::lambda::constant(std::string::npos) != boost::lambda::bind(
              static_cast<size_t(std::string::*)(const std::string&, size_t) const>(&std::string::find)
            , &content_id // pass by pointer, don't copy
            , boost::lambda::_1
            , 0
            )
    );
```

It looks most readable and elegant with [C++11 lambda](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/14/anonymous-functions-lambdas-in-c11/):

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = std::find_if(
      attachment_list_.begin()
    , attachment_list_.end()
    , [&content_id](std::string const& i) { return std::string::npos != content_id.find(i); }
    );
```

Further I noticed that `id` returned for unsuccessful search is 0. It is the same value that is returned when the search succeeds on the first element. In other words, the caller of this function won't be able to distinguish between an unsuccessful search and when the first (0th) element matched.

It is most simple and portable to use a plain loop for search here:

```
std::string* MimeDocument::GetAttachmentId(std::string const& content_id) {
    for(  std::vector<std::string>::iterator i(attachment_list_.begin()), j(attachment_list_.end())
        ; i != j
        ; ++i
        ) {
        if(std::string::npos != content_id.find(*i))
            return &*i;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Using this version the caller can easily tell between a successful and unsuccessful search and find out the matching index if necessary:

```
MimeDocument doc;
// ... populate doc
if(std::string* found = doc.GetAttachmentId("1")) {
    // the search was successful.
    size_t found_index = found - &doc.attachment_list_.front();
}
```

So, pick your poison...

Answer (score 2):

The parameter types to `bind` are not related to each other in any way (orthogonal template types), and only within the *body* could the compiler determine which overload of `find` is needed. In fact the compiler is only allowed to look at the function declaration to figure out what to pass in and there are ambiguous possible overloads of `find` and the compiler can't use the bound argument type to help figure out which one to use.

In this case I think it may work out simpler to just write a 5 line functor to do the nested string searches for you.