# How to decide if one string contains another string

Tags: c++, stl

I have one set of strings and then some second string. And I want to iterate through that set and decide if current string is contained in that second string. Is there any tool from `STL` or from any of these includes that can ease me that work?

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
```

Usecase:

```
test1 . Add    ( 0, "hello" );
test1 . Add    ( 1, "world" );
test1 . Add    ( 2, "rld" );
test1 . Add    ( 3, "ell" );
test1 . Add    ( 4, "hell" );
printSet ( test1 . Search ( "hello world!" ) );
// 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
printSet ( test1 . Search ( "hEllo world!" ) );
// 1, 2
```

Of course, I could compare it string by string, character by character or create some automaton, but why to make things harder, than they acutally are :)

Comment: [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) for search, and `boost::bind` to pass it into `std::for_each` with `boost::lambda` to compare result to `std::string::npos` and count them
You can find related example [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724363/using-boostbind-on-stdstringfind-fails-to-compile)
Another more straightforward approach  would be to create own functor that will take string in constructor, search for substring in `operator()(const std::string&)` and count npos'es

Comment: wouldn't you mind, to write short example, how `boost::bind` works?

Comment: or std::bind . . . or even a lambda

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/).

I hope this helps